# HTML: Behavior of nested scrollbars

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `jQuery` modal window that pops up when users perform a certain action.

This modal window has a little too much `height` for smaller screens, so users with smaller screens have to scroll the main window (not the modal window) down to see the 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons at the bottom of the modal window.

Also, this modal window sometimes has content that can be quite long, so every now and then a scrollbar will appear in the modal window to allow users to scroll through longer content. The 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons are not part of this scrollable area though, so they always appear at the same place.

Whether the modal has content long enough to scroll or not, users with smaller screens still have to scroll the main window to see the 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons at the bottom of the modal window.

My question is: How do I make the inner scrollbar (the one in modal popups with longer content), once scrolled completely to the bottom, pass control over to the outer scrollbar so that the user can scroll the main window's scrollbar down to see the 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons (without having to move the mouse to the outer window)? This question pertains to using the scroll wheel on the mouse, as having this bahavior when the user clicks on the scrollbar and drags would be strange and unintuitive.

I hope this makes sense :).

**NOTE:** Found this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60339/mouse-wheel-interaction-with-nested-scrollbars

The above link talks about the default scrolling behavior of IE:

"*The default windows paradigm seems to be:
scroll the area over which the mouse cursor currently resides
unless it is not possible to scroll further in that direction, in that case scroll the next higher level.*"

The OP of the question in the link seems to want to avoid this basic behavior (or "Inception Style" scrolling), but this is actually what I want in my case. It's not working in Chrome at least, but yes, this does seem to be the default behavior of IE.

"Inception Style" scrolling is explained well here:
http://baymard.com/blog/inline-scroll-areas, the section on "Scroll hijacking" is basically what I want to achieve in non-IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

UX law is simple: no nested scrollable areas on the screen.

In your particular case: you should make your modal window to always fit inside current view/window in full. Thus dailog OK/Cancel buttons shall be always seen without need of scrolling.

Usually modal dialogs use semi-transparent shim and so document's scrollbar are hidden. Therefore user will need to scroll only scrollable inside your dialog and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The overly high modal window only affects users with small screens (a small minority). And right now, resizing the modal is not an option. Also, IE seems to do what I want by default, see my NOTE above. Any way I can get this done in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: "resizing the modal is not an option" you have to create that option.  Modal windows that are larger than desktop or parent view as in your case are always considered as a UX/UI bug.